# Calculate Supremum of the taylor series of an holomorphic function

Tags: complex-analysis

let $t\in [0,1[$ and the function: $f_t(z) = \frac{z-t}{1-zt}$ which is holomorphic in the Open Disc $D(0,1)$.

I am trying to find $\sup_{|z|<1}|\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty} a_n z^n|$ where $\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty} a_n z^n$ is the Taylor series at $0$ of $f_t(z)$

What I did:

I calculated Taylor series at $0$ of $f_t(z)$:

$f_t(z)=-t + \sum_{k \geq 1}^{+\infty}z^k(t^{k-1} - t^{k})$

From here I don't know how to follow-up, Any help, a hint is much appreciated.

Many thanks!

Comment: I don't understand the title of your question. Your function is *not* entire.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos: I updated the question. I am actually trying to find the Sup of the Taylor series of $f_t$

Comment: But $f_t$ is **not** an entire function.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos: Oh sorry, I updated the title

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's holomorphic, so it can't have an interior maximum. Since $|t|<1$, the definition of $f_{t}$ extends perfectly well to $|z|=1$, so let $z = e^{i\theta}$ and investigate:

$$|f_{t}|^{2} = \frac{(z-t)(\bar{z}-t)}{(1-zt)(1-\bar{z}t)} = \frac{1-2\cos \theta t + t^{2}}{1-2\cos \theta t + t^{2}} = 1$$
so the supremum is $1$.

Alternatively, note that $f_{t}$ is a Mobius map, and hence sends circles and lines to circles and lines, and is determined by the images of any three distinct points in $\mathbb{C}$. The map sends $1\mapsto 1$, $-1\mapsto -1$ and $i \mapsto \frac{i-t}{1-it}$ (which has modulus $1$). So it sends the unit circle to itself, and by continuity it sends the whole unit disk to itself. In particular, $|z| \le 1 \implies |f(z)| \le 1$ (showing the supremum is attained is straightforward).

Comment: Great Answer thank you!
I am wondering if we can use the same technique  to calculate $\sup_{|z|\leq \frac{1}{3}}(\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}|a_nz^n|)$ where $\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}|a_nz^n|$ is the Taylor series of $f_t$?

I mean if $\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}a_nz^n$ is holomorphic,  does it imply that $\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}|a_nz^n|$ is also holomorphic ?

Comment: It certainly does not imply that - the power series $f(z) = z$ is holomorphic but $|z|$ is not. The series you give is a real power series (in the variable $|z|$), with positive coefficients. Does that help?

Comment: Cristal clear, many thanks!